# Getting error trying use textContent on an HTML error. "Unable to set property 'textContent' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows

Think I'm missing something bleeding obvious here and would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

I have the following code however when I run it breaks and says that .textContent cannot be applied to queryString because queryString is undefined.

What is throwing me however is that if I break the code just before this line and look at queryString it is storing the correct value which is `".titlearea .pagetitle"`. Why is this not translating in subsequent line?

The JSON object is converted into an object which returns two properties that I wish to use. A property called `termName` and another called `definition`. I want to replace the textContent of the two HTML elements with the values of these parameters.

I have stored the value of `termName` and `definiton` in an array called `content`. I do this in the `for...in` loop.

I then want to loop through this array and replace the relevant HTML element with the relevant value from the `content` array. This is the second `for` loop.

I basically want the line to be interpreted as:

document.querySelector(".titlearea .pagetitle").textContent = xxxx;

Where xxxx is the `queryResult[i]` value.

Here is the full code.

```
var searchTerm = JSON.parse(Result.responseText);
var DefDiv = ".titlearea .pagetitle";
var DescDiv = ".titlearea .pagesubtitle";
var holder = [DefDiv, DescDiv];
var content = [];
var x;

// Push the query into an array
for (x in searchTerm.terms[0].term) {
    content.push(x);
}

var displayResult = function(queryResult) {

    for (var i = 0; i <= holder.length; i++) {
        var queryString = holder[i];

        document.querySelector(queryString).textContent = queryResult[i];
    }
};

displayResult(content);
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: BTW `<=` should be `<` in the for loop.

Comment: Thanks David, how did you put the code so it has Javascript Syntax? I'll post the HTML in a second, I have however tested it hardcoding  `".titlearea .pagetitle" where querySelector should be and that does work fine.

Comment: All you have to do is indent four spaces. If you want inline code blocks, wrap the code in `\`\`` characters.

Comment: Also, what is inside `searchTerm.terms[0].term`?

Comment: Basically this code is inside a function that contacts my web service which returns a JSON object. I then use `JSON.parse` to convert that into an object which is `searchTerm`. Once converted searchTerm is a mixture of objects and arrays, do you want me to print it out exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the `<=` fix, I'd overlooked that.

Comment: Not quite sure how to display `searchTerm.terms[0].term` it's nested objects and an array so don't know how to write it out and it make sense. Sorry I'm fairly  new to this.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why it's returning undefined. I'm trying to look for a source.

Comment: Ok, let me try and clarify a few things, I'll update the original question once I have.

Comment: I've updated the question, I'm not sure if this helps... thankyou btw for your help and Merry Christmas!

Comment: What browser are you using for this?

Comment: Are you sure your querySelector call actually nets a result? It's quite possible that the the point your code is called, the element you expect to find isn't present, or you've got it typed wrong for when you do make that call. The error is because the result of the selector is null when you run it.

Comment: @DominicHopton If the selector isn't present then it will return `null`. He's not getting that error because it's null, but because `document.querySelector` returns undefined.

Comment: The message from ie actually says undefined or null reference. Are you sure it's undefined?

Comment: Thank you both for your time on this, please take a look at my comments below for what I think was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You tagged this as Windows 8, so I'm going to assume you're using some form of Internet Explorer. The thing is, some versions of IE don't support `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll`. I think this is your problem. Try logging these two methods and see what it says. If it returns `undefined` then there is no native support in that browser for those methods.</strike>

---

So it turns out it was because your were looping while using `<=` as part of the loop termination condition instead of `<` which I pointed out earlier but wasn't sure of that being the cause of the problem. Glad I could help anyway.

Comment: Windows only supports one version of ie - ie10, which does support query selector.

Comment: @DominicHopton So you're completely ruling out that `document.querySelector` returns undefined for the browser he's using?

Comment: No, i'm stating that IE's behaviour isn't "Variable" -- he stated windows 8. there is only one version of internet explorer available on that platform -- IE 10. That **does** support querySelector[All]

Comment: Sorry guys, I've been away. I maybe should have made it more explicit that I'm referring to Win 8 app development. So the Metro environment using JS/HTML/CSS.

Comment: I've managed to get my code working, and I actually think changing `<= `to `<` solved my issue. Thanks for that David, not as complex as you were maybe thinking but I told you it was probably simple! If you want to add it as an answer I'll mark it correct.